# ActiveRecord find and only return selected columns aligned with [:id]

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a set of data that is in two different tables. I want to join them up on my /show page in my ruby on rails app. In the controller, I have it set to find the date, set a variable, use that date to look through the other database to pull the needed information.

My controller looks like this:

```
  def show
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    @hellodate = Ticket.select(:date)
    @winnings = Winnings.find(:all, :conditions => {:date => @hellodate})

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html # show.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @ticket }
   end
 end
```

for my @winnings to work, I need it to pull the row that has the date that matches with the @ticket date. I am new to this world and would love any input / solutions because this isn't working. It should only show one @winnings but it shows multiple though only ONE date will eve match. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@hellodate` is not what you think it is. This:

```
@hellodate = Ticket.select(:date)
```

will, more or less, give you the result of saying:

```
select "date" from "tickets"
```

so you'll get all `Ticket`s but only the `date` columns will be pulled out of the database. Presumably you just want the `date` from `@ticket`:

```
@ticket   = Ticket.find(params[:id])
@winnings = Winnings.where(:date => @ticket.date)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly and my mistake now makes so much more sense. Thank you for your help on that.